# PHP compare between two times 24 hour format after 00:00 and before

Tags: php, time, strtotime

I am trying to compare two times one of which is in 12 hour format and the other is in 24 hour format, that is after 12am.

```
$time = date( 'H:i:s', current_time( 'timestamp', 0 ));
$open = '18:00';
$closed = '01:30';
if ( $time < $open || $time > $closed)
{
//do something
}
```

this is always failing it is something to do with the 01.30 because if I do anything less than 00:00 e.g. 23.30:

```
$time = date( 'H:i:s', current_time( 'timestamp', 0 ));
$open = '18:00';
$closed = '23:30';
```

The above works.

I have also tried strtotime like this without success.

```
if ( $time < strtotime($open) || $time > strtotime($closed))
```

How can I evaluate between 6pm and 2am in the morning?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are only comparing the current time (time right now), logically you don't have to worry about tomorrow's time. You only need to compare if you are inside/outside today's opening/closing times.

```
<?php
// SET RELEVANT TIMEZONE
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Dublin');

// CURRENT UNIX TIMESTAMP
$time_now = time();

// TODAY AT 18:00:00 (24 HOUR) UNIX TIMESTAMP
$opening_time = DateTime::createFromFormat('H:i:s', '18:00:00')->format("d-M-Y H:i:s"); // 11-May-2018 18:00:00

// TODAY AT 01:30:00 (24 HOUR) UNIX TIMESTAMP
$closing_time = DateTime::createFromFormat('H:i:s', '01:30:00')->format("d-M-Y H:i:s"); // 11-May-2018 01:30:00

// WE ARE CLOSED IF:
// TIME NOW IS AFTER CLOSING TIME TODAY (01:30:00)
// AND TIME NOW IS BEFORE OPENING TIME TODAY (18:00:00)
if($time_now > strtotime($closing_time) && $time_now < strtotime($opening_time))
{
    echo "Sorry, we are closed!";
}
else
{
    echo "We are open, come on in!";
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Much like when working with months and January being either the first month of this year or 13th month of last year, 1 am is either the 1st hour of today or the 25th hour of tomorrow.

I'd reverse your logic and determine if it is currently greater than 0130 and less than 1800.  Take out the colons and it makes it really easy

```
$close=013000;
$open=180000;
$now=date( 'His', time());

if (($close<$now)&&($now<$open)){
 print("Go away, we're closed");
}else{
 print("Welcome to the store!");
}
```

If you don't want to reverse the logic, then instead of using 01:30 use 25:30 for the value - PHP and `date` are pretty good about rolling over the next position when a larger than max value is used some place.